# Review audit failed for upvote I didn't make

Tags: bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19693655)  with the message:

> ## STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You
> didn't pass**. This post was of very poor quality, and needed
> significant improvements to be useful - upvoting such posts hurts the
> ability of others to find and answer good questions. Please try to fix
> such posts by editing, downvoting, closing, or flagging as "very low
> quality".
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately - but
> please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
> guidance above.

Even though I did, in fact, press edit - though maybe it was unsalvagable, I was just trying to improve the formatting, and in fact one of the suggested activities was edit, but it says I upvoted.

Comment: There's no attempt shown here, no third-party edit on this planet could fix that. Flag to close this stuff.

Comment: @LW001: The message says "Please try to fix such posts by **editing**, [other options...]", which is quite misleading if you're not supposed to edit.

Comment: Don't polish turds. Please flush them.

Comment: @Will No, I agree, but I didn't really understand the post and I thought some formatting might help. Had it worked, I would probably have flagged after understanding what the post was actually asking. The main question, however, is that I pressed edit, and the system said that I should have (among other things) edited it (which I tried to), rather than upvoting it (which I didn't).

Comment: So it looks like the concern is not the failed audit itself, but the message that accompanied it.

Comment: To be very pedantic about it though, it never says you upvoted. It's definitely implied from the phrasing... But the message just says 'upvoting this hurts the site' not that you upvoted it..... But yes it's heavily implied and should be improved.

Comment: @Patrice I agree. But it does say that one of the things I could do is edit it.

Comment: @JoeC Sort of. As far as I can tell, it thought I made an upvote. But maybe it's just that it's got a bad message when you try to edit a rubbish post

Comment: @ArtemisFowl as I said it was more of a pedantic point than anything else. I agree that in this specific situation it wasn't the best formulation for the message

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Did you actually edit the post such that it became a useful post that didn't merit closure anymore?  Editing a post such that *it's still a bad post after your edit* isn't helpful.

Comment: @Servy I didn't edit it at all. I clicked the edit link, and got the message. I couldn't understand the question very well, so I wanted to edit it to make it more clear, even if only to then flag it.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl That you don't even think you could have edited it into a good post is rather proving its point then.

Comment: @Servy I realise this, however the message implied that I had upvoted, and said that among other thing what I should have done was to edit it.